# Static imports in java

Tags: java

Is `static imports` making my code incomprehensible?

If I have static a variable in a class, and I call it in another class:

`MainClass.java` :

```
public static String NAME = "Jack";
```

and:

`AnotherClass.java` :

```
textView.setText(MainClass.NAME);
```

What if I just made that in `AnotherClass`?

```
import static com.example.MainClass.NAME;

// ..Some code..

textView.setText(NAME);
```

Will this make it incomprehensible for anyone will read it later?

Comment: It's a bit OT to CodeReview - what about http://programmers.stackexchange.com? Anyway, I would say that it's not about comprehensibility. Static import should be used when you want to import only static members or methods of the class. However there is no significant performance difference between the two imports.

Comment: I asked that because when i try to read my code later for ex. after month of more i take long time to realise that variables is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be answered with a definitive yes or no. First of all, this is a subjective question. But for most readers of code, it depends on several factors.

- How much code is there? If your file is only 20 lines long, the whole thing fits on one screen and thus `import static` is less likely to cause confusion.
- How related is the name of the member to the name of the class? Static import of `Foo.FooException` will be fairly easy for readers to understand. Static import of `Foo.Exception` will be fairly difficult.
- Is the class in the same package as this one? Understanding code in one class often requires some knowledge of other classes in the same package, so same-package static imports are more likely to be appropriate.
- Is the member well-known in some context? For example, in unit tests it is often appropriate to `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals`.